# 1 Kafka topic with consumer filters vs. many topics without consumer filters

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to adopt Kafka technology for a distributed system that is consuming tick data from financial exchanges in real-time and not sure what approach makes the most sense in this use case:

I am consuming data for several thousand stocks and each consumer only cares about consuming data for a handful of stocks up to 100 symbols. Am I better off creating a topic for each stock and having the consumer subscribe to the list of topics it cares about or is it better to have 1 topic where all the tick data is published and the consumer uses a filter to only consume the messages it cares about?

I don't know if there are message selectors in Kafka like JMS and also don't know what option will offer better performance. Any feedback or answers are appreciated, the goal is to minimize latency as much as possible. - Duncan

Comment: There is no broker side filtering. Depending on the network load you are willing to accept, and if you can split you data to different topics in a meaningful way for your consumers, it might be a good idea to have multiple topics.

Comment: Do you think its a large overhead for a JVM process to be consuming from a 100 kafka topics at the same time?

Comment: Hard to say in general... As far as I know, internal consumer memory buffer is shard over multiple topics -- also CPU overhead should not be large. Network overhead might depend on overall number of partitions that all might have a different leader broker. Depending on you cluster size, using more topics (and thus, maybe more partitions) might result on more connection as  you might need to connect to more brokers. But I am not an expert on consumer client internals...

Comment: **Message Selectors:**  you can partition the data based on a key, and this partition can be processed by separate consumer threads.
**Better Performance:**  Performance can be achieved by parallelism and in Kafka the smallest unit of parallelism is the partition of a topic.

Comment: See also this open issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1448